# Probability of a result based on given probability distribution

Tags: probability

Let's say that I have 3 teams A, B and C, competing in a competition.

For each team, here are the probabilities of finishing 1st, 2nd and 3rd:

| Team | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50% | 25% | 25% |
| B | 25% | 50% | 25% |
| C | 25% | 25% | 50% |

Now, what is the probability that each results (ABC, ACB, BAC, ...) happen?

I'm a beginner in maths, and I have no idea what I'm doing.

I tried multiplying (p(ABC) = p(A1) * p(B2) * p(C3)) and additions, using the minimum (p(ABC) = min(p(A1), p(B2), p(C3)), etc. But the results don't make sense to me, or the sum of the probabilities isn't 1.

(Let me know if I'm not clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you are missing is, that as soon as you know who is first, the probabilities of who comes in second place change. For example, consider the simpler case of just two teams $A,B$. Say $A$ has a probability of $\frac{3}{4}$ of coming in first, and a probability of $1-\frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$ of coming in second place, and for $B$ it is the other way around.

Then, if you draw a tree diagram, you see that first you have two paths, with probabilities $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$, respectively. However, the next step has just one option in each branch, so those two branches will have probability $1$. (If $A$ is first, the probability of $B$ being second is just $100$%.)

Just do this for the larger case, then the probabilities you get in the end will add up.

Comment: Of course! That makes more sense! Thank you

Comment: Speaking more formally, you are dealing with conditional probabilities here. Note that the events are not independent.